# Error converting string, '2015-08-23', to date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerbi

I am trying to clean my data prior to loading into PowerBI to create the visuals.  I have created my query as:

```
CREATE VIEW Project2 AS (
 Select 
  p.playerID as ID1, 
  p.birthYear, 
  p.birthMonth, 
  p.birthDay, 
  p.birthCity, 
  p.deathYear, 
  p.nameFirst, 
  p.nameLast, 
  p.nameGiven, 
  p.weight, 
  p.bats, 
  p.throws, 
  p.finalGame, 
  b.*
  from dbo.People as p
      LEFT JOIN dbo.Batting as b
   ON p.playerID=b.playerID
   and b.G >= 50
   WHERE (p.finalGame is null or p.finalGame >= 2018));
```

This works great until attempting to load the view into PowerBI I get this error:

> DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2015-08-23' to data type int.
> Details:
> DataSourceKind=SQL
> DataSourcePath=laptop-o4rhi9q7;Baseball
> Message=Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2015-08-23' to data type int.
> ErrorCode=-2146232060
> Number=245
> Class=16

I can't figure out where /how to utilize `cast(p.finalGame as date)` in correct syntax, any ideas?

Comment: Aside: `select Cast( DateAdd( day, 2018, 0 ) as Date );` returns July 12, 1905. Is that really the date you want to check against in your `where` clause?

Answer (score 1):

You must use a proper date literal for this, which means it must be enclosed in quotes, and ideally use a [non-ambiguous format](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly)

```sql
WHERE (p.finalGame is null or p.finalGame >= '20180101'));
```

---

If `finalGame` is actuall `varchar` you would need to convert it using an appropriate conversion type. For example

```sql
WHERE (p.finalGame is null or CONVERT(date, p.finalGame, 102) >= '20180101'));
```

That may not be the correct format number, the full list is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles).

I urge you to change the column type to `date` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If the data for p.finalGame = '2015-08-23', you'll need to cast that as a date in your WHERE clause.

```
   CREATE VIEW Project2 AS (
    Select 
     p.playerID as ID1, 
     p.birthYear, 
     p.birthMonth, 
     p.birthDay, 
     p.birthCity, 
     p.deathYear, 
     p.nameFirst, 
     p.nameLast, 
     p.nameGiven, 
     p.weight, 
     p.bats, 
     p.throws, 
     p.finalGame, 
     b.*
     from dbo.People as p
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Batting as b
      ON p.playerID=b.playerID
      and b.G >= 50
      WHERE (p.finalGame is null or cast(p.finalGame as DATE) >= 2018));
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this did help.  I am still getting an error and even attempted to change  the where state and also as :WHERE (p.finalGame is null or Format(convert(datetime, p.finalGame, 101), 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= 2018));     However still getting an error when loading to powerBI

Comment: What does the data look like for "b.G"?

Comment: You don't want to wrap a function around a column name. That would have significant performance implications. SQL Server would have to run that function on every row in the table instead of using an index to find a single row. See the answer froM Charlieface. It's the correct answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, you date appears to be a string of the form 'yyyy-mm-dd', not a true date type or an integer year. I believe your fix is to quote your year. Either

```
WHERE (p.finalGame is null or p.finalGame >= '2018');
```

or

```
WHERE (p.finalGame is null or p.finalGame >= '2018-01-01');
```

If your year is a variable, convert it to a string with something like `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Year)`. (This assumes a 4 digit value.)

As already noted, a better approach (if you have the ability to change the schema) is to redefine finalGame as a true DATE or DATETIME type. Then you could compare `p.finalGame >= '2018-01-01'` or `p.finalGame >= DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 1, 1)`.